`error: linker `cc` not found` when installing AVM on WSL
Got this error below when install AVM on WSL
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: could not compile `crossbeam-utils` (build script) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `libc` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `rayon-core` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `proc-macro2` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `parking_lot_core` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `signal-hook` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: could not compile `thiserror` (build script) due to 1 previous error
error: failed to compile `bacon v3.1.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installsG2bp8`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.


Doing this on a fresh install I had to install the necessary packages
sudo apt update

install
sudo apt install build-essential

